# Use Sum() Case() and Over() in a single statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query, where I'm already using a `ROW_NUMBER()` function. My question is, is it possible to use it too, on `cash, debit` and `credit`? Because I'm getting duplicated data in every item row, I want to only get the first row of each payment type to pair them with the totalsale column.

My attempt:

```
SELECT 
    i.Name,
    i.Coditem,
    Pt.docnumber,
    pt.doctype,
    i.ItemPrice,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Pt.Paymentid = 01 THEN pt.Amount END) AS 'Cash',
    SUM(CASE WHEN Pt.Paymentid = 02 THEN pt.Amount END) AS 'Debit',
    SUM(CASE WHEN Pt.Paymentid = 03 THEN pt.Amount END) AS 'Credit',
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.doctype, i.docnumber ORDER BY i.coditem) = 1
            THEN s.totalsale 
    END AS TotalSale
FROM 
    PaymentsTable AS Pt
INNER JOIN
    ItemSales I ON i.docnumber = pt.docnumber
LEFT JOIN
    sales s ON (s.docnumber = i.docnumber)
GROUP BY 
    Pt.docnumber, pt.doctype, i.name, i.coditem, 
    i.itemprice, s.TotalSale, i.doctype, i.docnumber
```

Here's the example database

[Dbfiddle Test Db](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=10f28a39528935c40090eca8f589ef24)

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: The same as the totalsale, i need just the first row of cash debit and credit, i just need the first row of them, and not repeated into every row that contains the same docnumber

Comment: then use `row_number()` as what you have done for TotalSale

Comment: would you type the syntax?

Comment: @RoyGivenchi, can you post the expected output in the question? Thanks.

Comment: While a dbfiddle can be extremely helpful, it must be in addition to a self contained question, i.e. your question must still contain the sample data and desired results without needing to access an external link which may become invalid over time.

Comment: Ok, got it, I'm still kind of noob here, but you've been really helpful in every answer/comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or derived table to simplify your query so that you don't need to perform `GROUP BY` on every column in your result

```
-- Tables & Sample data are from your db<>fiddle link. 
-- Reproduced here fore ease of reference
create table PaymentsTable (
PaymentId varchar(10),
DocNumber varchar(20),
DocType varchar(40),
Amount decimal(18,2));

create table ItemSales(
Name varchar(20),
DocType Varchar(20),
DocNumber varchar(20),
CodItem varchar(15),
ItemPrice decimal(18,2));

create table sales(
DocNumber varchar(20),
DocType varchar(20),
TotalSale decimal(18,2));

insert into paymentstable values (01,2020, 'receipt', 100);
insert into paymentstable values (02,2020, 'receipt',150);
insert into paymentstable values (03,2020, 'receipt',10);
insert into paymentstable values (01,220, 'invoice', 650);
insert into paymentstable values (02,220, 'invoice',500);
insert into paymentstable values (01,600, 'order', 1500);

insert into ItemSales values ('P1', 'Receipt', 2020, 010203, 100);
insert into ItemSales values ('P2', 'Receipt', 2020, 010204, 100);
insert into ItemSales values ('P3', 'Receipt', 2020, 010205, 60);
insert into ItemSales values ('Table', 'Invoice', 220, 'Tb05', 300);
insert into ItemSales values ('Bed', 'Invoice', 220, 'b01', 850);
insert into ItemSales values ('toaster', 'Order', 600, 'T01', 1500);

insert into sales values (2020, 'receipt', 260);
insert into sales values (220, 'invoice', 1150);
insert into sales values (600, 'order', 1500);
```

The modified query

```
SELECT I.Name
     , I.Coditem
     , S.DocNumber
     , Pt.doctype
     , I.ItemPrice
     , CASE WHEN I.ItemNo = 1 THEN Pt.Cash     END AS Cash
     , CASE WHEN I.ItemNo = 1 THEN Pt.Debit    END AS Debit
     , CASE WHEN I.ItemNo = 1 THEN Pt.Credit   END AS Credit
     , CASE WHEN I.ItemNo = 1 THEN S.TotalSale END AS TotalSale
FROM sales S
     INNER JOIN 
     (
         -- generating the row_number in sub-query, makes it easier
         -- for outer query to reference the ItemNo
         SELECT Name
              , DocType
              , DocNumber
              , CodItem
              , ItemPrice
              , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY DocType, DocNumber 
                                       ORDER BY CodItem) AS ItemNo
         from   ItemSales 
     ) I                         ON I.DocNumber = S.DocNumber
     INNER JOIN 
     (
          -- pivoting query as what Dale show you in your last question
          SELECT Pt.DocNumber
               , Pt.DocType
               , SUM(CASE WHEN Pt.PaymentId = 01 THEN Pt.Amount END) AS 'Cash'
               , SUM(CASE WHEN Pt.PaymentId = 02 THEN Pt.Amount END) AS 'Debit'
               , SUM(CASE WHEN Pt.PaymentId = 03 THEN Pt.Amount END) AS 'Credit'
          FROM   PaymentsTable Pt
          GROUP BY Pt.docnumber, Pt.doctype
     ) Pt                         ON I.DocNumber = Pt.DocNumber
```

Side note: please be consistent with your table naming. You have table `sales` in lower case while the rest are in camel case. Also use the same case in your query as in your table DDL.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, possible approaches are:

- A combination of `PIVOT` relational operator and `DENSE_RANK()` function
- Conditional aggregation

Statement using `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT 
   Name, CodItem, DocNumber, DocType, ItemPrice, 
   Cash = CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Cash END, 
   Debit = CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Debit END,
   Credit = CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Credit END, 
   TotalSale = CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN TotalSale END 
FROM (
   SELECT 
      i.Name, i.CodItem, pt.DocNumber, pt.DocType, i.ItemPrice, pt.Amount, s.TotalSale,
      CASE
         WHEN pt.Paymentid = 01 THEN 'Cash'
         WHEN pt.Paymentid = 02 THEN 'Debit'
         WHEN pt.Paymentid = 03 THEN 'Credit'
         ELSE 'Other'
      END AS PaymentId,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY i.DocType, i.DocNumber ORDER BY i.CodItem) AS rn
   FROM PaymentsTable AS pt
   INNER JOIN ItemSales i on i.docnumber=pt.docnumber
   LEFT JOIN Sales s on (s.docnumber=i.docnumber)
) t
PIVOT (
   SUM(Amount) FOR PaymentId IN ([Cash], [Debit], [Credit])
) p
ORDER BY DocNumber, DocType
```

Statement with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    Name, CodItem, DocNumber, DocType, ItemPrice, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Paymentid = 01 AND rn = 1 THEN Amount END) AS 'Cash',
    SUM(CASE WHEN Paymentid = 02 AND rn = 1 THEN Amount END) AS 'Debit',
    SUM(CASE WHEN Paymentid = 03 AND rn = 1 THEN Amount END) AS 'Credit',
    CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN TotalSale END AS TotalSale
FROM (
   SELECT 
      i.Name, i.CodItem, i.ItemPrice, 
      pt.DocNumber, pt.DocType, pt.Amount, pt.PaymentId,
      s.TotalSale,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY i.DocType, i.DocNumber ORDER BY i.CodItem) AS rn
   FROM PaymentsTable AS pt
   INNER JOIN ItemSales i on i.docnumber=pt.docnumber
   LEFT JOIN Sales s on (s.docnumber=i.docnumber)
) t   
GROUP BY DocNumber, DocType, Name, CodItem, ItemPrice, CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN TotalSale END
```

Result:

| Name | CodItem | DocNumber | DocType | ItemPrice | Cash | Debit | Credit | TotalSale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 10203 | 2020 | receipt | 100.00 | 100.00 | 150.00 | 10.00 | 260.00 |
| P2 | 10204 | 2020 | receipt | 100.00 |  |  |  |  |
| P3 | 10205 | 2020 | receipt | 60.00 |  |  |  |  |
| Bed | b01 | 220 | invoice | 850.00 | 650.00 | 500.00 |  | 1150.00 |
| Table | Tb05 | 220 | invoice | 300.00 |  |  |  |  |
| toaster | T01 | 600 | order | 1500.00 | 1500.00 |  |  | 1500.00 |